# How to plot Directions between two locations in iOS Swift using mapView and CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I am using `mapView.showUserLocation = true` to plot user location and display it as an Annotation on my `MKMapView` object.

Now, when I have obtained the users' location, I want to plot a path from that set of coords to my destination. I tried using `MKDirections` for this

Here is how I was trying to do it:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    print("test")
    //Setting Up Source Location
    let sourceLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate
    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
    let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    sourceAnnotation.title = "You are Here"

    if let location = sourcePlacemark.location {
        sourceAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }

    //Setting Up Destination Location
    let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.6621292, longitude: 77.30198310000003)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
    let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    destinationAnnotation.title = "Conclave is Here"

    if let location = destinationPlacemark.location {
        destinationAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }


    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
    self.mapView.showAnnotations([sourceAnnotation,destinationAnnotation], animated: true)


    //Plotting a course from Source to Destination
    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
    directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .Automobile

    // Calculate the direction
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

    // 8.
    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler {
        (response, error) -> Void in

        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                //print("Error: \(error)")
            }

            return
        }

        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapView.addOverlay((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)

        let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
    }

}
```

However, when I tried debugging it, I get the following error:
`Error: Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=5 "Directions Not Available" UserInfo=0x1742f7600 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A route could not be determined between these locations., MKErrorGEOError=-403, MKDirectionsErrorCode=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available}`

I did some research and found out that `MKDirections` in not available in **India**, so I was wondering how to can get around showing Navigation Directions to the user.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Best option to use GOOGLEPLACEAPI for get direction and placeinformation .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=5 "Directions Not Available"
```

You are most likely to get this error if the location doesn't belong to any of the countries in this list: http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions

While on iOS simulator, you can easily customize your current location. Two ways to do it:

**iOS Simulator -> 'Debug' tab -> Location -> {Choose}**

**Xcode -> 'Debug' tab -> Simulate Location -> {Choose}**

**So i suggest you to Use this.** GoogleMaps SDK and draw route.

https://gist.github.com/himanshu-benzatine/10670936c8f16ea1ae482bc6bb684adc

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful. Just wondering, If I were to port that code from C# to Swift, will any changed be have to be made apart from the syntax?

Comment: Yes if you changes the code from c# to swift then syntax and its method will be changes.

Answer (score 4):

Better to use google api to draw polyline from source & destination. You can use the api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=%@&destinations=%@&key=

Then you get the json data of lat long(s) from where path can be drawn. Decode the json data and draw polyline in MKMapkit

Comment: Google maps and Apple maps don't have the same underlying data. If you do this, your route might draw over non existent roads in Apple maps, or be located a few metres away from where the road is drawn in Apple maps.

Comment: If you're going to do this, you should use the Google Maps SDK instead of using Apple Maps.